# wizard django заполнение формы n-ого шага введенными данными в прошлых шагах

Tags: python-3.x, django

Задача следующая : на первом шаге wizard загружаем файл. на 3 шаге из этого файла надо вытащить информацию и составить список из нее. я не могу понять, как подтянуть эту информацию к следующему шагу, хотя знаю, что все , что ввели wiard хранит.

Comment: Слишком абстрактный вопрос. Если хотите получить на него абстрактный ответ - то это называется парсинг файла загруженного из формы. Делается, например через view. Так как больше никакой информации Вы не предоставили - это всё, что можно ответить на Ваш вопрос, так как ни исходников ни формата файла нет...

Comment: формат файла .txt
это таблица с большим количеством строк

Comment: Ну я бы делал так: Визард каждому юзеру, загружающему данные выдавал бы свой токен. По этому токену всегда можно определить, какие данные загрузил юзер. Далее несколько страниц со своими url/формами-вопросами/ обработчиками. Можно даже на ajax смастерить, часть задачи переместить на фронтэнд в java, усложняет задачу, но делает более изящной.  Это если кратко...

Comment: я пытаюсь получить данные шага данным методом(у меня немного переработан он, добавил обработчик файла):
 def get_form_initial(self, step):

        # steps are named 'step1', 'step2', 'step3'
        current_step = self.storage.current_step
        
        # get the data for step 1 on step 3
        if current_step == 'step3':
            prev_data = self.storage.get_step_data('step1')
            some_var = prev_data.get('step1-some_var','')
        
            return self.initial_dict.get(step, {'some_var': some_var})

        return self.initial_dict.get(step, {})

Comment: но у меня не выходит загрузить их в шаблон, выдает пустые значения, хотя в консоли выводит необходимые=\